# Occasional "Invalid object name '##gmnv'."

Tags: sql, vba

This code might run 5 times in a row before showing this error. It is part of a button in a Excel sheet that puts data into a SQL database.

```
'Delete the previous linked doc if it exists. Match up with quote number.
If fileType = ".xlsb" Then
    con.Execute "delete from CONTSUPP where LINKEDDOC like '%" & Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("G7").Value & "%' AND LINKEDDOC like '%" & Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("B11").Value & "%.xlsb%' "
ElseIf fileType = ".pdf" Then
    con.Execute "delete from CONTSUPP where LINKEDDOC like '%" & Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("G7").Value & "%' AND LINKEDDOC like '%" & Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("B11").Value & "%.pdf%' "
End If

rs.Open "select LINKEDDOC from CONTSUPP where LINKEDDOC like '%" & savePath & "%' "
If rs.EOF Then
    'Open database connection
    rs.Close

    Sql = "" & _
    "declare @gmnv varchar(20), @recid varchar(15) " & _
    "set nocount OFF " & _
    "EXEC Castell_Create @gmnv OUTPUT " & _
    "EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'accountno', '" & Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("N22").Value & "' " & _
    "EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'filename', '" & savePath & "' " & _
    "EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'user', 'MASTER' " & _
    "EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'notes', '' " & _
    "EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'ref', '" & Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("G7").Value & "-" & Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("B11").Value & "' " & _
    "EXEC Castell_WriteLinkedDoc @gmnv " & _
    "EXEC dbo.Castell_Delete @gmnv"

    con.Execute Sql
Else
    'MsgBox "Link found!"
    Exit Function
End If
```

This is an example with the actual data that generated this message formatted to look nicer.

```
declare @gmnv varchar(20), @recid varchar(15) set nocount OFF 
EXEC Castell_Create @gmnv OUTPUT 
EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'accountno', 'A3081527308)*83QWAmo' 
EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'filename', '\\acs03\gmapp\Quotes\Bill_Fegley\Deer_Ridge_Construction\bf19-191_Wise\bf19-191_Wise_BLD_QUO_Construction.pdf' 
EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'user', 'MASTER' 
EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'notes', '' 
EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'ref', 'bf19-191-Wise' 
EXEC Castell_WriteLinkedDoc @gmnv 
EXEC dbo.Castell_Delete @gmnv
```

Comment: What have you done to debug it? Obviously we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Normally VBA will give me a starting point. It just says something in this is the problem and I don't really know where to start. I've tried removing as much of the SQL statement as possible, but it still gives this message sometimes.

Comment: I would start by exec'ing the commands one-at-a-time. Break up the Sql into smaller chunks and run multiple con.Execute commands